# VARCHAR to numeric conversion, scientific notation causing conversion error - advice needed

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I had a similar thread earlier that has evolved into a difficult problem that I may think does not have a real solution. Hopefully, I am wrong but here is the gist.

I defined the data types for each member of the table to be Varchar(80). I then load the data from an external system (Oracle PBCS) to a flat file using an integrator tool that loads the data to a table.

Through a transformation SQL process - I cast or convert the data from varchar to numeric or decimal. When I do this I get an error on some values. Using a try_cast query - I can see what the culprits of why I cannot cast or convert to numeric or decimal.

The extract loads these values in scientific notation - not sure why the source system fully does that - so I decided to try to control for it in the SQL - but unfortunately nothing is working as I have to convert first to float before I convert to numeric or decimal. For very small values such as 6.27e^-19 - my float just reduces the fraction of the cent to 0 - in general float just seems like a very bad idea for currency.

If I keep the try_cast then I will return null values - I really can't be doing that.

See code below

```
1.455191522836685e-11
1.455191522836685e-11
1.455191522836685e-11
1.455191522836685e-11
1.455191522836685e-11
1.455191522836685e-11
1.455191522836685e-11
1.455191522836685e-11
1.455191522836685e-11
```

These are my problem items via try_cast.

```
select 
   t.[acct_20010]
   --convert(numeric(19,4), convert(float, t.[acct_20010]))
  --cast( cast(t.[acct_20010] as float) as decimal(18,10))
  -- ,CAST([Obligated] AS FLOAT)  
  --  ,CAST([Total_Expended] AS FLOAT)     
              --  ,CAST([Total_Obligated_FAMIS] AS FLOAT)
    --,CAST([Spendplan_Balance] AS FLOAT)
    --,CAST([Pending_Expenditures] AS FLOAT)
     --           ,CAST([Unexpended_Balance] AS FLOAT)
    --,CAST([Funds_Remaining_by_BBFY] AS FLOAT)
    --,CAST([PY_Funds_Remaining] AS FLOAT)
--select t.[expended]
--from 
from
(select [acct_20010] as [acct_20010]
--,[obligated],
--Total_Expended
FROM [BFS_DM].[Source].[Cld_Ess_SpendPln] where ([acct_20010] is not null and [acct_20010] <> '#missing'))  t
where TRY_CAST(t.[acct_20010] AS NUMERIC(18,4)) IS NULL
```

I just need some guidance of how possibly I can convert the scientific notation values (without using excel as this is an automated process) to numeric or decimal.

If I loaded the file to a table that has proper data types - would it even accept a scientific notated value?

Comment: The values in your question convert just fine to float (https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=5e5df2f531c95a466d9a8d905248ebca).  Perhaps you have some unseen characters in the string.

Comment: Hi Gordon, thanks for your help! Currently, the extract that comes out and loaded into a table are string values. Most of these values convert fine to numeric in a sql select - but the query never returns a result after a transform to numeric because of the "bad exponential notation" entries.

Comment: I just get the error "unable to convert varchar to numeric". so I used the try_cast to try to find the values that when converting to numeric(18,4) return null - which means those are the bad entries. All of these return the scientific exponential notation. Unfortunately, when I try_cast or these to float and then numeric, I lose the 1.455191522836685e-11 becomes 0.0000. Even when I just do a cast as float with numeric - 1.455191522836685e-11 becomes 1.45519152283669e-11. So floating in general is problematic. but it seems with exponential - all is lost in terms of getting into to be

Comment: .0000000001455191522836685 - is my desired output

Answer (score 1):

Exponential notation is not valid for a string-to-numeric conversion.  Consider the following:

```
select try_cast('1.455191522836685e-11' AS numeric(18,4))
select try_cast('1.455191522836685e-1' AS numeric(18,4))
select try_cast('1.455191522836685' AS numeric(18,4))
```

Only the last one works because it does not have an explicit exponent.

You can fix this, if you must, by first converting to a float then to numeric:

```
select try_cast(try_cast('1.455191522836685e-11' as float) AS numeric(18,4))
select try_cast(try_cast('1.455191522836685e-1' as float) AS numeric(18,4))
select try_cast(try_cast('1.455191522836685' as float) AS numeric(18,4))
```

Watch precision, though -- you'll notice the first example yields 0 as a result.

Comment: Hi All, thanks for the comments. Since I have these scientific notated values in exponential - is there a way then I can screen the exponent out as I have found that fractions of a cent get reduced to zero. I need to retain that cent as is.

Comment: Please provide some concrete examples of inputs and desired outputs and I'll see if I can help.

Comment: Hi BoCoKeith, thanks for your help! Currently, the extract that comes out and loaded into a table are string values. Most of these values convert fine to numeric in a sql select - but the query never returns a result after a transform to numeric because of the "bad exponential notation" entries. I just get the error "unable to convert varchar to numeric".

Comment: Continuing on, so I used the try_cast to try to find the values that when converting to numeric(18,4) return null - which means those are the bad entries. All of these return the scientific exponential notation. Unfortunately, when I try_cast or these to float and then numeric, I lose the 1.455191522836685e-11 becomes 0.0000. Even when I just do a cast as float with numeric - 1.455191522836685e-11 becomes 1.45519152283669e-11. So floating in general is problematic. but it seems with exponential - all is lost in terms of getting into to be .0000000001455191522836685

Comment: 1.455191522836685e-11 is .000000000014551915..., so, naturally, a conversion to a 4-digit decimal value is going to yield 0.0000.  What were you expecting?